# A requested plan item is not enabled for this account. This account is not enabled for Smart Sections. why am I getting this error

Tags: docusignapi, docusignconnect

In the docuSign live account I am getting an error like this even though I have't enabled any smart sections or responsive signing options in my production account,And I am not getting this error in the demo docuSign account.why is there a need to enable this feature is there any way to get rid of this error.

Comment: I'm getting the same thing, although aren't using any "smart sections" to my knowledge either. I've opened a support case with DocuSign.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Smart Sections is an optional feature. It is included in the developer accounts. It is included with some paid production accounts but not with others.

You can update your question with the API request log and we can figure out why you're getting the error.

If you don't use the feature then you won't receive the error.